# Prove $(\rho_1 \rho_2 \cdots \rho_r)^u = e \implies e=\rho_1^u=\rho_2^u=\cdots=\rho_r^u$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

In the proofwiki page: [Order of Product of Disjoint Permutations](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_Product_of_Disjoint_Permutations)

We have a product of disjoint permutations $\pi = \rho_1 \rho_2 \cdots \rho_r$. Why exactly is it that if $\pi^u=e$, then for each $\rho_s$ we have $\rho_s^u=e$, where $e$ is the identity permutation? I think we will have if they are not all $e$, then there will be at least 2 permutations $\rho_{s_1}$, $\rho_{s_2}$ where $\rho_{s_1}=\rho_{s_2}^{-1}$, which somehow contradicts the disjoint assumption, but I wasn't able to prove $\rho_{s_1}=\rho_{s_2}^{-1}$. I was able to prove only that $\rho_{s_1}^u=\rho_{s_2}^{-u}$, from which we can say

$\rho_{s_1}^u=\rho_{s_2}^{-u}$

$\implies \rho_{s_1}^u \rho_{s_2}^{u} = 1$

$\implies (\rho_{s_1} \rho_{s_2})^{u} = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some $k$ and let $S_k$ be the set which is acted upon by $\rho_k$ (the elements which $\rho_k$ actually moves). By disjointedness, none of the other $\rho_i$'s act on any of the elements of this set. So, when applying the entire permutation $u$ times, which results in the identity, the set $S_k$ only sees you apply $\rho_k^u$. Thus we must have $\rho_k^u=e$.

Comment: "By disjointedness, none of the other $\rho_i$'s act on any of the elements of this set." This intuition is EPIC! Thank you!

Comment: @JackBauer What did you think "disjoint" meant?

Comment: Just that they commute (I didn't realize other properties were relevant, so I didn't bother to analyze the definition of disjoint), which I'm now realizing is that weaker than disjoint. :)

Comment: Arthur, may I please double check: inverses are not disjoint, is that right?

Comment: @JackBauer Apart from the identity permutation (which is its own inverse and still disjoint), no they're not.

Comment: I forgot about that. Thank you!

Comment: Arthur, could I please get your thoughts on disjointedness in my new question? [Alternative proof that the 3-cycles generate the alternating group $A_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950053)

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $\rho_i,\rho_j$ are disjoint permutations, then $\rho_i^n,\rho_j^m$ are also disjoint permutations for any $m,n\in\mathbb N$. Also note that if a product $\prod_i\rho_i$ of mutually disjoint permutations is $e$, then each of them is $e$, otherwise say $\rho_1=(1\ 2\cdots)$, then $\prod_i\rho_i$ sends $1$ to $2$, and is not $e$.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think your answer, at least for the second sentence, argues against exactly one of them is not $e$. My argument is that if one of them is not $e$, then *another one* isn't $e$ too. To have the product equal to $e$, one is the inverse of the other so $\rho_{s_1}^u=\rho_{s_2}^{-u}$. As for your first sentence, what does it mean for $\rho_{s_1}^u$ and $\rho_{s_2}^{u}$? Inverses are not disjoint?

Comment: I was trying to express the same idea as that of Arthur in fact. Because other permutations will not affect the elements acted by any one of the permutations, if the product is $e$, then everyone of them is $e$.

Answer (score 0):

$\rho_{s_1}$ and $\rho_{s_2}$ are disjoint if and only if $\rho_{s_1}^{m}$ and $\rho_{s_2}^{n}$ are disjoint.

Choose $m=n=u$.

If $(\rho_{s_1})^u (\rho_{s_2})^u = (\rho_{s_1} \rho_{s_2})^{u} = e$, then $\rho_{s_1}^{u}$ and $\rho_{s_1}^{u}$ are not disjoint because every permutation can be represented as the product of disjoint cycles. In this case, the representation $(\rho_{s_1})^u (\rho_{s_2})^u = e$ is not a disjoint representation of $e$. Therefore, $(\rho_{s_1})^u$ and $(\rho_{s_2})^u$ are not disjoint. Therefore, $\rho_{s_1}$ and $\rho_{s_2}$ are not disjoint. This contradicts our assumption.